# Explanation of "itf" parameter of visitMethodInsn in ASM 5

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

With ASM 5, original `MethodVisitor.visitMethodInsn()` is deprecated. A new parameter called `itf` was added. The API reference says it means "if the method's owner class is an interface".

But I think `opcode` should be `INVOKEINTERFACE` and `itf` should be true if the owner is an interface, `opcode` should be `INVOKEVIRTUAL` and `itf` should be false if the owner is an ordinary class. `itf` should always be inferable from `opcode`.

What's the point of the additional argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ASM 5 adds support for Java 8 bytecode format which allows static methods in interfaces, so at least `invokestatic` is now possible on interface methods.

Comment: `invokespecial` can be applied to interfaces as well, e.g. to call an inherited `default` method.